# iOS 9 AVAsset issue

Tags: ios, ios9, assets

I am facing a critical issue right now
I am asking this since I was not able to find solution by googling.
I am working on input/output audio with AVAsset file.  However, when I test, there are no issues in iOS8
but in iOS9, there are times that only audio is being played while video is stopped.  
There are no issues when I take out the file while the video is stopped.
This issue does not come up when I play the original AVAsset file, but if I create AVAsset file through code below and play, error above arises time to time.
I need to solve this problem but I was not able to find any solution.  Please help.

```
AVAsset *asset = _recordSession.assetRepresentingSegments;

AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

NSError *error;

AVAssetTrack *video = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:video atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];

if (error != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"compositionVideoTrack error = %@", error);
}


if ([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count > 0) {
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack *audio = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject];
    [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:audio atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];

    if (error != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"audioTrack error = %@", error);
    }

}

AVAsset *playAsset;
playAsset = mixComposition;
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?